# Find $a$ so that $f$ has a specific local extreme point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We are given a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2 - ax}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}, a \in \mathbb{R}$$

Find $a$ so that the function $f$ has a point of local extreme situated at a distance of $2$ from the $Oy$ axis.

The derivative of a function in a local extreme point is $0$. Calculating the derivative of $f$ and then equalizing with $0$, I got $x^3 + 2x - a = 0$.

At this point I got stuck.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $x=2$ should be one of the solutions

Comment: Substitute $x=2$ into the equation, and then find $a$. (You could do the same for $x=-2$.)

Comment: ... at least one between $x=-2$ or $x=2$ should be a root of that polyomial. Does this happen for all $a$ ?

Comment: The last step is to verify that $f''(2)\ne 0$ for $a_1$ and  $f''(-2)\ne 0$ for $a_2$.

Answer (score -1):

let $$h(x)=x^3+2x-a$$

$$h(2)=0 \rightarrow a=13$$

$$h(-2)=0 \rightarrow a=-13$$

When $-13 \lt a \lt 13$,  $h(2) \gt 0$ and $h(-2) \lt 0$ 
Thus by intermediate value theorem, there is a $c \in (-2, 2)$ such that $h(c)=0$. We can conclude there is an critical point within (-2, 2).